# Why WOL don't boot my system anymore?

Tags: ethernet, wakeonlan

a few days ago I managed wakeonlan to work on my pc, I was able to turn it on via lan successfully. I installed ethtool, run `ethtool -s eth0 wol g`, checked that `Wake-on: g` was displayed with `ethtool eth0`, shut it down, wake from another pc in the same lan with `wakeonlan xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`. Everything was fine and the sun was shining.

Now, it doesn't work anymore and I didn't changed anything, at least I don't remember I had.
I suppose there is no problem with sending the packet since I can see the magic packet broadcast over the lan with wireshark, I set a mac binding in the router anyway, just to be sure. I also tried to send the packet with `wakeonlan -I 192.168.0.166 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, the ip is static. Nothing.

Is it possible that the packet is not arriving when the computer is turned off?
I have no idea what the problem is, I would really appreciate any suggestion...!

Comment: What OS uses the machine you want to boot up?

Comment: @Braiam sorry how could I forget to mention, ubuntu 12.04!